# Заливка текста от края экрана

Tags: css

Всем привет!
Никак не получается продлить красную заливку влево от текста. Подскажите плз.

```css
.rengen_title .rentgen {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.88);
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.rengen_title .rentgen span {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="rengen_title">
  <span>Травмпункт</span><br />
  <div class="rentgen"><span>рентген</span></div>для взрослых и детей
</div>
```

[image: Должно быть вот так]
Должно быть так

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать псевдоэлемент `before`. Размер псевдоэлементу можно задать в зависимости от размера основного родителя, или просто использовать `100vw`, тогда блок гарантировано будет доходить до конца экрана.

```css
.rengen_title .rentgen {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.rengen_title .rentgen:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.88);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.rengen_title .rentgen span {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rengen_title">
    <span>Травмпункт</span><br />
    <div class="rentgen"><span>рентген</span></div>для взрослых и детей
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: на секунду линия появляется в нужном месте и пропадает. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Разобрался. В родительском блоке поставил z-index: 1;
Спасибо!